# Sitecore.Kernet Package installation from Nuget Package Manager error

Tags: nuget

[image][image][image]

When I am trying to install Sitecore.Kernel or any other package from Nuget Package Manager i am getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue, do the following.

1. You need to upgrade the current .net framework to `.NETFramework 4.8`
2. Then you need to install `Sitecore.Kernel 10.2.0`,

Then it should resolve the issue.

For more reference use this link.

https://sitecore.myget.org/feed/sc-packages/package/nuget/Sitecore.Kernel

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0087164

Comment: Still same issue .NetFramwork 4.8 already installed

Comment: what is the framework of your solution? is it in 4.8?